# Pandas plot, combine two plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Currently I have 3 plots that I am plotting in the 2x2 subplots. It looks like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
df1.plot('type_of_plot', ax=axes[0, 0]);
df2.plot('type_of_plot', ax=axes[0, 1]);
df3.plot('type_of_plot', ax=axes[1, 0]);
```

The 4-th subplot is empty, and I would like the 3-rd one to occupy the whole last row.

I tried various combinations of axes for the third subplot. Like `axes[1]`, `axes[1:]`, `axes[1,:]`. But everything results in the error.

So how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
a=fig.add_axes((0.05,0.05,0.4,0.4)) # number here are coordinate (left,bottom,width,height)
b=fig.add_axes((0.05,0.5,0.4,0.4))
c=fig.add_axes((0.5,0.05,0.4,0.85))

df1.plot('type_of_plot', ax=a);
df2.plot('type_of_plot', ax=b);
df3.plot('type_of_plot', ax=c);

plt.show()
```

see also the [documentation of add_axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)

The `rect` coordinate I gave you are not very readable, but you can easily adjust it.

EDIT: Here is what I got : [image]

Comment: It doesn't look like the 3-rd plot occupies the last row. Also the margins between the plots disappear.

Comment: I changed the values of the rect and added an image of the graph I got